# Why aren't my scala futures more efficient?

Tags: multithreading, performance, scala, scalability, future

I'm running this scala code on a 32-bit quad-core Core2 system:

```
def job(i:Int,s:Int):Long = {
  val r=(i to 500000000 by s).map(_.toLong).foldLeft(0L)(_+_)
  println("Job "+i+" done")
  r
}

import scala.actors.Future
import scala.actors.Futures._

val JOBS=4

val jobs=(0 until JOBS).toList.map(i=>future {job(i,JOBS)})
println("Running...")
val results=jobs.map(f=>f())
println(results.foldLeft(0L)(_+_))
```

(Yes, I *do* know there are *much* more efficient ways to sum a series of integers; it's just to give the CPU something to do).

Depending on what I set JOBS to, the code runs in the following times:

```
JOBS=1 : 31.99user 0.84system 0:28.87elapsed 113%CPU
JOBS=2 : 27.71user 1.12system 0:14.74elapsed 195%CPU
JOBS=3 : 33.19user 0.39system 0:13.02elapsed 257%CPU
JOBS=4 : 49.08user 8.46system 0:22.71elapsed 253%CPU
```

I'm surprised that this doesn't really scale well beyond 2 futures "in play".  I do a lot of multithreaded C++ code and have no doubt I'd get good scaling up to 4 cores and see >390% CPU utilisation if I coded this sort of thing with Intel's TBB or `boost::threads` (it'd be considerably more verbose of course).

So: what's going on and how can I get the scaling to 4 cores I'd expect to see ?  Is this limited by something in scala or the JVM ?  It occurs to me I don't actually know "where" scala's futures run... is a thread spawned per future, or does "Futures" provide a thread pool dedicated to running them ?

[I'm using the scala 2.7.7 packages from Debian/Squeeze on a Lenny system with sun-java6 (6-20-0lennny1).]

**Update:**

As suggested in Rex's answer, I recoded to avoid object creation.

```
def job(i:Long,s:Long):Long = {
  var t=0L
  var v=i
  while (v<=10000000000L) {
    t+=v
    v+=s
  }
  println("Job "+i+" done")
  t
}
// Rest as above...
```

This was so much faster I had to significantly increase the iteration count to run for any amount of time!  Results are:

```
JOBS=1: 28.39user 0.06system 0:29.25elapsed 97%CPU
JOBS=2: 28.46user 0.04system 0:14.95elapsed 190%CPU
JOBS=3: 24.66user 0.06system 0:10.26elapsed 240%CPU
JOBS=4: 28.32user 0.12system 0:07.85elapsed 362%CPU
```

which is much more like what I'd hope to see (although the 3 jobs case is a little odd, with one task consistently completing a couple of seconds before the other two).

Pushing it a bit further, on a quad-core hyperthreaded i7 the latter version with `JOBS=8` achieves an x4.4 speedup vs JOBS=1, with 571% CPU usage.

Comment: You're just impatient, wanting the future today!  Seriously, Rex hit the nail on the head, you're benchmarking garbage collection, not futures efficiency.

Comment: Heh... too true.  When I submitted this question I'd not been using Scala that long, and was probably a bit too credulous of some of the extreme hype surrounding it.

Comment: care to re-run the test with akka.dispatch.Future?

Comment: @Viktor: Well this was submitted before I had access to 2.8.  Now 2.8 has turned up parallel collections have pretty much obsoleted futures for parallelising compute (they still have good uses relating to managing asynchrony of course).  Last time I looked at scala parallel performance I got some (good) results shown in the "performance" box of this poster: http://timday.bitbucket.org/project_euler-poster.pdf And as Rex notes below, the real issue is whether object churn kills the garbage collector.  Any particular reason Akka would fare better there ?

Comment: I've hear reports that Akka 2.0 Futures can beat ParCol under certain circumstances. Akka Futures also use 0 locks and are very tiny.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My guess is that the garbage collector is doing more work than the addition itself.  So you're limited by what the garbage collector can manage.  Try running the test again with something that doesn't create any objects (e.g. use a while loop instead of the range/map/fold).  You can also play with the parallel GC options if your real application will hit the GC this heavily.

Comment: Yup, that does seem to be the case; see 2nd version of code and results in question update.  The issue originally came up in some code making heavy use of BigInts so not much chance to eliminate object creation there.  Hadn't appreciated how much of an impact this sort of stuff could have... scala seems to eliminate the need for much explicit new-ing in code so it's easy to forget it's still there.

Comment: Shouldn't the compiler optimize this `new`'s away?

Comment: @Elazar - Eventually with specialization, it _may_ be possible for that (or something similar) to run without object creation.  For now, though, it's unavoidable: the code is generic, so you have to create the object for it to work on even if it is just a wrapper over a primitive.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
(i to 500000000 by s).view.map(_.toLong).foldLeft(0L)(_+_)
```

The application of `view` is supposed to (as I understood id) to avoid repeated iteration and object creation by providing simple wrappers.

Note also that you can use `reduceLeft(_+_)` instead of fold.

Comment: I'm still on 2.7.7; view is not a member of Range for me (hopefully 2.8 will turn up in the Debian archive one day; I'm to lazy to build from source, and all the Scala books I have are about 2.7).  Glad to see there's some improvements being made in this area though.  (And yes I'd generally prefer reduce to fold unless there's some good reason; in this case it was because there's no guarantee some extreme i/s parameters to the function won't lead to one or zero elements for the reduction operation).

Comment: Yea, I noticed that, too. You can download Scala 2.8.1 in a tgz that you just have to unpack anywhere (e.g. `/usr/share/`). Then create symlinks to the scripts in subfolder `bin` and you are gold. I'd really be interested how the three variants perform on 2.8.1 on your machine (I do not have a quad-core myself).