# Why is Scala good for concurrency?

Tags: scala, concurrency

Are there any special concurrency operators, or is functional style programming good for concurrency? And why?

Comment: For concurrency, you must consider Erlang also. And its OTP framework is awesome

Answer (score 48, accepted):

At the moment, Scala already supports two major strategies for concurrency - **thread-based** concurrency (derived from Java) and **type-safe Actor-based** concurrency (inspired by Erlang). In the nearest future (Scala 2.9), there will be two big additions to that:

- [**Software Transactional Memory**](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/8359) (the basis for concurrency in Clojure, and probably the second most popular concurrency-style in Haskell)
- [**Parallel Collections**](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/150220/files/pc.pdf) (without going into detail, they allow for parallelizing basic collection transformers, like `foreach` or `map` across multiple threads).

Actor syntax (concurrency operators) is heavily influenced by Erlang (with some important additions) - with regards to the library you use (standard actors, Akka, Lift, scalaz), there will be different combinations of question and exclamation marks: `!` (in the most cases for sending a message one-way), `!!`, `!?`, etc.

Besides that, first-class functions make your life way easier even when you work with old Java concurrency frameworks: ExecutorService, Fork-Join Framework, etc.

Above all of that stands immutability that simplifies concurrency a lot, making code more predictable and reliable.

Comment: You missed data-flow concurrency, made possible through lazy vals and by-name params.  I'd also say that fork-join is a paradigm in its own right, closely related to parallel collections.

Comment: what is type-safe Actor based concurrency?

Answer (score 16):

There are a number of language features that make Scala good for concurrency.  For example:

- Most of the data structures are immutable and don't require anything special for concurrent access.
- The functional style is a really good way to do highly concurrent operations.
- Scala includes a really handy "actor" framework that helps with concurrent asynchronous operations.

Further reading:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-scala02049.html

[http://blog.objectmentor.com/articles/2008/08/14/the-seductions-of-scala-part-iii-concurrent-programming](https://web.archive.org/web/20121018000226/http://blog.objectmentor.com/articles/2008/08/14/the-seductions-of-scala-part-iii-concurrent-programming)

http://akka.io

Answer (score 10):

Well, there is the hype and there is the reality. Scala got a fame for being good for concurrency because it is a functional language and because of its actors library. Functional languages are good for concurrency because they focus on immutability, which helps concurrent algorithms. Actors got their reputation because they are the base to Erlang's track record of massively concurrent systems.

So, in a sense, Scala's reputation is due to being a "me too" of successful techniques. Yet, there is something that Scala does bring to the table, which is its ability to support such additions to the language through libraries, which makes it able to adapt and adopt new techniques as they are devised.

Actors are not native to Scala, and yet there are already there different libraries in wide use that all seem to be. Neither is transactional memory, but, again, there are already libraries that look like they are.

They, these libraries, are even available for java, but there they are clunky to use.

So the secret is not so much what it can do, but that it makes it look easy.

Comment: "So, in a sense, Scala's reputation is due to being a 'me too' of successful techniques." You say that almost like it's a bad thing.

Answer (score 7):

The big keyword here is immutability. See [this Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object#Scala). Since any variable can be defined as mutable or immutable, this is a big win for concurrency, since if an object cannot be changed, it is thread safe and therefore writing concurrent programs is easier.

Comment: "immutable variable": I always loved exactly how nonsensical that phrase truly is...

Comment: @Kevin: yep, somebody needs to invent a new word for that phrase.

Comment: I tend to say "reference" now.  So I can be explicit about "immutable reference to a mutable value", or "mutable reference to an immutable value".  It works quite well for me in practice.

Comment: How about the word "value"? Immutable value.

Answer (score 3):

Just to rain on everyone's parade a bit, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627367/why-arent-my-scala-futures-more-efficient).

I've dual-coded a fair few multithreaded things in Scala (mainly using Futures, a bit with Actors too) and C++ (using TBB) since then (mostly Project Euler problems).  General picture seems to be that Scala needs ~1/3 the number of lines of code of the C++ solution (and is quicker to write), but the C++ solution will be ~x10 faster runtime (unless you go to some efforts to avoid any "object churn", as shown in the fast version in the answer referenced above, but at that point you're losing much of the elegance of Scala).  I'm still on 2.7.7 mind you; haven't tried Scala 2.8 yet.

Using Scala was my first real encounter with a language which strongly emphasised immutability and I'm impressed by its power to hugely simplify the mental model you have to maintain of object "state machines" while programming (and this in turn makes coding  for concurrency easier).  It's certainly influenced how I approach C++ coding.

Comment: I'd love to see if there'd be any difference in performance if you'd implement it using Akka Actors.

Comment: First, Scala is in its infancy; we can expect that, as with Java, its performance will improve as its compiles mature.  Second,  a computer costs about 8¢ an hour if you rent it from Amazon Web Services, while a beginning programmer costs about $80 an hour fully loaded (i.e., including costs of benefits, office, &c).  If it takes one hour longer to write a program in C++, that's more expensive than letting its Scala equivalent run SIX WEEKS longer .  Third, choosing a language because it's faster at run time is a prime example of premature optimization, which we've all been warned against.

Comment: Malvolio: That's only if a six week delay in results has no costs (opportunity costs, people waiting, etc). Having a six weeks turnaround time for something can cost millions of dollars.

Comment: @Malvolio: I absolutely agree the bigger picture needs to be considered; that's why I've stuck with Scala for the Project Euler problems.  The minimal value to me of squishing a 20s Scala runtime down to 2s in C++ is completely outweighted by the convenience and rapidity with which of "exploratory" programming can be done in Scala to figure out the algorithm needed to solve the problem.  Further, the PE problems seem well designed to resist brute-forcing, so a bad 10 hour solver in Scala isn't any more attractive as a 1 hour C++ run, at least if you apprach the problems in the spirit intended.

Comment: @Viktor: Why might I expect Akka to be any more efficient ?  My general suspicion is that object churn in garbage collected VM languages (particularly with immutability leading to object creation instead of mutation of existing objects) can lead to the GC becoming something of a bottleneck (I'm sure I've read this effect mentioned in connection with Haskell parallelization efforts somewhere on SO too).  Hopefully this will improve in time as the VM/GCs become more tuned for this workload of course.

Comment: @Viktor -- too bad there's only one computer in the world, and we all have to line up to use it, so if a task takes six weeks of computer time, it won't be done for at least six weeks.  If only there were some way to get several computers and put them all to work on the same problem... :)

Comment: @Viktor -- (seriously) there are lots of ways to improve the total elapsed time it takes for a program to complete. Parallelization is one; careful profiling and keyhole optimization is another; re-writing key sections in C++, C, or Assembler is a third.  Writing the whole thing ab-initio in C++, C, or Assembler is probably the most expensive (per second saved) way to improve performance.

Comment: @Malvolio: Yes I know, I just felt it better for me to ask that question than to have it served as critique by someone else.

Comment: @timday: Akka performance compared to Scala Actors performance usually is between x2 to x4: http://doc.akkasource.org/file/view/akka-bench-throughput.png/178397193/akka-bench-throughput.png

Comment: @Viktor -- Does this dialogue sound familiar: Some Random Idiot: [Language X] is too slow?  You: No problem, we'll write it in [Language X] and then find the hotspots and rewrite them in [Language W, the simple-minded but supposedly faster predecessor to Language X]. Some Random Idiot: OK.  I've had this conversion a dozen times and I've never actually had to rewrite anything.